# PHP function with array

Tags: php, function

Just got the coding question about php

```
==============html input form=========================
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="iphone">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="3">
 
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="samsung">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="6">
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="IBM">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="3">

==============PHP code(part1)==============
function productlist($itemname,$itemquantity) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($itemname);$i++)
    {
        echo $itemname[$i] .",". $itemquantity[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
$message = productlist($itemname, $itemquantity);

==============PHP code(part2)==============
$to = "abc@abc.com";
$subject = "Online order form";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

part1 result:
iphone,3
samsung,6
IBM,3
```

Question:
the coding can run with part 1 result, may i know how to pass part1 result into part2 and can send out successfully.

thx so much

Comment: Are they included in the same file?

Comment: The `productlist()` function has to `return` something if you want to call is like `$message = productlist($itemname, $itemquantity);` and NOT `echo` anything

Comment: return an array to implode or a concatenated/built string or use ob_start/ob_get_clean, lots of ways but simply echoing is not correct

Comment: The question could have better been posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds like you need `implode` and an array.

Answer (score 1):

Readonly is a Bool value so you don't have to set it to anything. Not that you should trust data from the client. It can be easily over written.

Your server will have to be configured to send email. If it's not that's a different problem to work on.

```
==============html input form=========================
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly value="iphone">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="3">
 
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly value="samsung">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="6">
<input name="itemname[]" type="text" readonly value="IBM">
<input name="itemquantity[]" type="text" value="3">

==============PHP code(part1)==============
$message = productlist($_POST['itemname'], $_POST['itemquantity']);

function productlist($itemname,$itemquantity) {
  $message = '';
  for($i=0;$i<count($itemname);$i++){
    $message .= $itemname[$i] .",". $itemquantity[$i]."<br>";
  }
  return $message;
}

==============PHP code(part2)==============
$to = "abc@abc.com";
$subject = "Online order form";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```